# How we can chek if the files are empty while uploading multiple files simultaneously in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How we can check if the files are empty while uploading multiple files simultaneously in codeigniter?

```
<input type="file" name = "user_file[]"  multiple />
<input type="file" name = "user_file[]"  multiple />
```

Controller Code:

```
if (empty($_FILES['user_file']['name'])) {

   echo'<script>alert("please upload a file or write something")</script>';
   exit();
}
```

But it is not working, empty files also uploading?? please anyone provide solution for this ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
if (filesize($file_path) == 0){
    echo "The file is empty";
}
```

or also try

```
if (trim(file_get_contents($file_path)) == false) {
     echo "The file is empty";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is empty.";
}
```